# How to use exception stack trace after process dead

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, debugging

probably my question is due to my "beginnery"; however...
I'm using netbeans and I wrote a project.
Then I start my project with debugger but without break points, hoping that at exception occurrence I could eventually read variable values to understand which instruction is the problem.

An example:
let's suppose I have a piece of code like this:

> to[m][k]=from[i][k];

then at execution it launches a NullPointerException at that line of code...
Ok, then debugger ends and I can't read variables that caused the exception and moreover in that line of code there are 4 index operations so I can't understand which one of the 4 really caused the exception.
Thank you

Comment: And why not set the breakpoint there?

Comment: because that code is inside a nested loop of 2,8M of cycles and I can't stay pressing F7 till I reach the exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that line is down inside a bunch of nested loops, I could imagine you wouldn't want a breakpoint there.

In eclipse, you can set breakpoints on exceptions in addition to on particular lines of code.  I'd look for a similar feature in NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

1. put a breakpoint on that line
2. ask netbeans to stop on exceptions: Tools -> Miscellaneous -> Java Debugger -> General and check "Stop on uncaught exception".

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why you are not setting break points?
In this case, if you set a break point at `to[m][k]=from[i][k];`, the program will break at this point giving you a chance to read `m` and `i` values

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint and then set its properties to break on exception. That will give you a chance to see what's going on.